# Inno Setup update disk space after changing components checkbox state from code

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I got a list of components (applications) that I can select to install (by default they are all checked) and all of those components got `ExtraDiskSpaceRequired`. On the start, I dynamically change which applications should be checked or unchecked depending on are they installed and some other conditions.

Now problem is when I check components (`TNewCheckListBox` items) from code on start "Disk space required" label is not updated until I change state of some checkbox from the list by mouse or keyboard.

I tried to fix it with:

- `WizardForm.Repaint` and other methods like that
- Changing state of checkboxes when that page is being shown
- Trying to send Space button down and up with `SendInput` from Windows API but it returns 0 (not pressed). I called `SendInput` in `CurPageChanged` function when wpSelectComponents is shown and from Timer

  Code I used for `SendInput`:

  ```pascal
  type
      TKeyboardInput = record
          Itype: DWORD;    
          wVk: WORD;
          wScan: WORD;
          dwFlags: DWORD;
          time: DWORD;
          dwExtraInfo: DWORD;
      end;

  function SendInput(nInputs: UINT; pInputs: TKeyboardInput;
      cbSize: Integer): UINT; 
      external 'SendInput@user32.dll stdcall';

  function SendKeyPressed(KeyCode: Word): Boolean;
  var
      InputDown: TKeyboardInput;
      InputUp: TKeyboardInput;
  begin
      Result := False;

      InputDown.Itype := 1;
      InputDown.wVk := KeyCode;
      InputDown.wScan := 0;
      InputDown.time := 0;
      InputDown.dwFlags := 0;

      InputUp.Itype := 1;
      InputUp.wVk := KeyCode;
      InputUp.wScan := 0;
      InputUp.time := 0;
      InputUp.dwFlags := 2;

      MsgBox(IntToStr(SendInput(1, InputDown, SizeOf(InputDown))),
        mbInformation, MB_OK);
      Result := SendInput(1, InputUp, SizeOf(InputUp)) = 1;
      if Result then
      begin
          MsgBox('Test2', mbInformation, MB_OK);
      end;
  end;
  ```

Any idea how can I solve this?

Example by default:

- CheckBox1       5MB checked
- CheckBox2       7MB checked
- Disk space label 12MB

Example after changing state by code on start:

- CheckBox1       5MB checked
- CheckBox2       7MB unchecked
- Disk space label is still 12MB until I change state of checkbox by mouse or keyboard

Note: I am using Inno Setup 5.6.1 (u) and can not update for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigger `TNewCheckListBox.OnClickCheck` event after you update the state of the list checkboxes:

```pascal
WizardForm.ComponentsList.OnClickCheck(WizardForm.ComponentsList);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried TNewCheckListBox.OnClick but it didn't work but didn't try this event :)